# Copy as curl is not working anymore in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, curl

For some time now, I'm not able to use the "copy as curl command" anymore. It's just an empty context menu, please see attached screenshot. Anyone else experienced the same issue?

I'm running chrome 90.0.4430.30 on a mac[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working fine for me on version 89.0.4389.90. I'm guessing that since version 90 is relatively new it has some bugs. Perhaps try downgrading back to the previous version or try reaching out to [Google Support](https://support.google.com/?hl=en).

[image]